# Are there any books on rational zeta series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

On the wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_zeta_series) on Rational zeta series, two references to articles on the subject are listed. So far, I have not been able to find a book on this topic. Are there any? And if so, could you recommend one?

Comment: See [here](https://www.morebooks.de/store/gb/book/rational-zeta-series/isbn/978-613-1-37021-2), for example.

Comment: @DietrichBurde In the description of that book, it is stated that the content mostly consists of articles available from Wikipedia and other free resources. I find such a disclaimer somewhat discouraging. I hope another treatment exists

Comment: No, that is not discouraging.  You can find a lot. Also, there are several hundred books on the Riemann zeta function. And in many of them there may be a chapter or a section on rational zeta series. One cannot expect a book on each single subject.

Comment: Well, I don't really expect it, I merely hope for it. As for the books on the Riemann zeta function, I will check them out and see if any of then contains an elaborate section or chapter on rational zeta series.